# Using UCC SSL certificate on multiple servers

Tags: exchange-2010, ssl-certificate, terminal-server

I have a UCC SSL certificate for my Exchange server, and want to add an SSL certificate to my terminal server. Is it reasonable to add another Subject Alternate Name to the same certificate and use it for both servers?

Comment: Sure, although some providers may consider this a license violation.

Comment: @ceejayoz - the amount of money these people charge for UCCs, they can take their license violation and stick it you-know-where

Comment: As someone who works for a company that forbids SAN certs, I feel your pain.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Agreed entirely. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead with this and it worked as expected.